# CDNJS old Javascript libraries

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I wanted to use Knockback.js to my project, but CDNJS in NetBeans 7.4 offers me only version 0.17.2, but the latest version is 0.18.2.

How is it possible to get the latest version of Knockback.js with CDNJS or is it possible to use somehow node.js' npm in a Netbeans project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dialog where you select JS files to import to project, there is a "Update: Never", if you click on it, it will updates list of offered JS libraries (it takes some time). However, NetBeans offers JS files from CDNJS.com, where Knockback is only in version 0.17.2, so update action in NetBeans won't help you (now, once CDNJS.com starts to offer 0.18.2, update action will help)